# Refresh System Variable in PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell

Thank you for all the help I get here!
I researched a lot on the Internet (and StackOverFlow) but I believe there is no way I can add a `System Variable` within a script and somehow "restart" or "refresh" so that `$env:MyTools` can be populated :( I'll have to exit and request the user to restart PS.

```
$AddCheck = Start-Process powershell.exe -verb runAs -ArgumentList '-Command', "`"[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('MyTools','C:\SomeFolder',[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)`";" -PassThru -Wait

if($AddCheck.ExitCode -eq 0)
{
Write-Host "[+] Addition Successful. Please restart PowerShell for changes to take effect!" -foregroundcolor green
""
"Exiting.."
sleep -s 5
stop-process -Id $PID
}
else
{"Something went wrong."}
```

Any help/inputs would be appreciated!

Comment: What's wrong with just `$env:MyTools = 'C:\SomeFolder'`? Why is it important that it gets set machine-wide?

Comment: I am using a PowerShell profile script with lots of functions which will load them every time a user runs PowerShell. One of the functions is to set the Tools Directory. So.. that variable will be lost if user closes the session. I was hoping to have the user add that variable just one (machine wide) and on subsequent sessions, he/she won't have to worry about it. Every analyst stores their tools in a DIR of their liking.. Sorry if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: more context= D:\Forensics\Tools\ I was hoping to have one variable added machine-wide. This is a one time action for that user. Now whenever they need artifacts parsed (each function parses an artifact using different tools all in the same DIR) they won't need to input the DIR everytime they fire up PS (which loads the profile script in memory).

Comment: you could just load it using `$env:mytools = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('mytools','machine')`. $env:mytools is only populated at startup, but its both a read and write property so you can set whatever you want with it.

Comment: THANK YOU! You guys are the best. That was all I wanted. I thought I would be able to fetch the value by `$env:VariableName` I didn't realize I needed to fetch it explicitly like you mentioned.